# Customize pytest collecting tests

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to avoid using the "test" prefix in classes and functions names and implement my own schema of the test parametrization.
I did the next code
test.py

```
import pytest

# class for inheritance to avoid "Test" prefix
class AtsClass:
    __ATS_TEST_CLASS__ = True

# decorator to mark functions as tests (to avoid "Test" prefix)
def ats_test(f):
    setattr(f, "__ATS_TEST_CLASS__", True)
    return f

def test_1():
    pass

@ats_test
def some_global_test():
    pass

class MyClass(AtsClass):
    def test_4(self):
        pass

    @ats_test
    def some_func(self):
        pass
```

conftest.py

```
import pytest
import inspect

# @pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_pycollect_makeitem(collector, name, obj):
    # outcome = yield
    # res = outcome.get_result()
    if inspect.isclass(obj) and obj.__name__ != "AtsClass" and hasattr(obj, "__ATS_TEST_CLASS__") and obj.__ATS_TEST_CLASS__ == 1:
        print("WE HAVE FOUND OUR CLASS")
        return pytest.Class(name, parent=collector)
        # outcome.force_result(pytest.Class(name, parent=collector))
    if inspect.isfunction(obj) and hasattr(obj, "__ATS_TEST_CLASS__") and obj.__ATS_TEST_CLASS__ == 1:
        print("WE HAVE FOUND OUR FUNCTION")
        return pytest.Function(name, parent=collector)
        # outcome.force_result([pytest.Function(name, parent=collector)])


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    print("-->Generate: {}".format(metafunc.function.__name__))
```

In this case hook "pytest_pycollect_makeitem" creates test for function "some_global_test", but hook "pytest_generate_tests" is not executed for function "some_global_test".

I have found a solution, call `collector._genfunctions(name, obj)` from my hook. But I think it is not the right decision, cause `_genfunctions` is a private method and not declared.

Is there another way to solve my task?

Comment: `pytest` includes only test functions/classes by matching their names against globs in [`pytest_classes`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-python_classes)/[`python_files`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-python_files)/[`python_functions`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-python_functions), but I guess you already know that and don't want to use them?

Comment: yes, I do not want to use any prefix,I would like to implement my own schema.

Answer (score 4):

So, nobody knows the answer and I decided to offer my solution (it can be useful for others):

```
    class TestBaseClass:
        __test__ = True

    def mark_test(f):
        setattr(f, "__test__", True)
        return f

    # using base class and decorator
    class MyTestClass(TestBaseClass):
        @mark_test
        def some_func(self):
            pass
```

Pytest uses attribute `__test__` to detect nose-tests, so you can use nose-library or just use such base class and decorator.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to change *prefix* of tests you can set custom `python_functions`and `python_classes` options at `pytest.ini`.

For more information follow a [link](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions).

Comment: No, I do not want to use any prefix.